# Laravel 5.8 use middleware for 1 user type in api and app

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I'm trying to implement a middleware in Laravel 5.8 which checks if a value is true for a model `Customer`. I want the app routes to redirect to a route (`'login'`), for the api routes I want to give a 401 response. I think I'm overseeing something.

This is my Middleware which works for the app routes, but I can't get the middleware to handle the unauthorized requests (`$user['dropshipping'] === false`) correctly..

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if($user instanceof Customer) {
        if ($user->guard(['web'])['dropshipping']) {
            return $next($request);
        } elseif($user->guard(['customer-api'])['dropshipping']) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect(route('login'))->with('error', 'Account not activated, please contact TWM BV.');
        }
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Guards are associated to Auth not to users.

So you can use `Auth::guard('guard-name')`  or `auth()->guard('guard')`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if($user instanceof Customer) {
        if (auth()->guard('web')->user()->dropshipping) {
            return $next($request);
        } elseif(auth()->guard('customer-api')->user()->dropshipping) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect(route('login'))->with('error', 'Account not activated, please contact TWM BV.');
        }
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this.. and it doesn't work for me. `auth()->guard('web')->user()` and `auth()->guard('web')->user()` return `null`. Without the guard do get the user thats associated with the current request.